# Catch the room_no value to a variable as Integer

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Is it possible to catch the value as integer to a variable?

```
public static function update_booking_status(){
    Global $pdo;
        $qry="SELECT rooms.room_no from rooms,booking where booking.tdate < CURDATE() and booking.room_no=rooms.room_no";//Catch the room_no
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->execute();
        $d=(int)$stmt;
        operations::delete_from_booking_status(($d);
}
```

Comment: Why should you want to cast PDOStatement object to int `$d=(int)$stmt;`? I really don't get you...

Comment: You want `room_no` as a variable?

Comment: did you mean $$ ?

Comment: yes, I want room_no as a variable @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted correctly you are trying to use the `room_no` for the next operation by attempting to return the value from the initial call to `$stmt->execute()`??

One way you could try if you like if that is the case...

```
/* simple callback supplied to `fetchAll` */
function getid( $room_no ){
    return $room_no;
}


$qry="SELECT `rooms`.`room_no` from `rooms`,`booking` where `booking`.`tdate` < CURDATE() and `booking`.`room_no`=`rooms`.`room_no`";//Catch the room_no
$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $qry );
$result = $stmt->execute();

if( $result ){

    $room_no=$stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_FUNC, 'getid' );
    $d=intval( $room_no[0] );

    operations::delete_from_booking_status( $d );
}
```